# get local image path from json in react

Tags: reactjs

How to pick the local path of image

**Json**

```
"avatarUrl": "avt1.jpg"
```

All the images are under **src>img** folder.
I am looking for absolute path + image name from json.

How I can achieve this
**reactJs**

```
<img src={require('./img/avt1.jpg')} width="60" />
```

Package.js

```
{
  "name": "lummdb",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "moment-timezone": "^0.5.14",
    "react": "^16.0.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.0.0",
    "react-fontawesome": "^1.6.1",
    "react-scripts": "1.0.16",
    "axios": "^0.17.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
}
```

Comment: are you using webpack?

Comment: no , I updated my package.js file

Comment: @faisal you are using react-scripts wich already uses webpack   على كل حال يمكنك الإطلاع على إجابتي أدناه

Comment: @AbdennourTOUMI so how can solve this issue?

Comment: I will update the answer.

Comment: answer was updated :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Seems you are using **create-react-app** , try to add `NODE_PATH=src` in your environment variable , or append it to script alias

```
   "start": "NODE_PATH=src react-scripts start",
```

If you are done, you can do the following :

```
<img src={require('img/avt1.jpg')} width="60" />
```

Then, if you are getting the name of image from json dynamically :

```
<img src={require(`img/${avatarUrl}`)} width="60" />
```

If does not work, consider to export NODE_PATH before :

```
 export NODE_PATH=src;
 npm start;
```

Comment: Answer was updated. It must work, if not, you need to review your question .

Answer (score 6):

Move all of your images to the `public/images`.

JSON file:

```json
{
  "title": "something",
  "image_link": "../images/yourfilename1.jpg"
},
{
  "title": "something2",
  "image_link": "../images/yourfilename2.jpg"
}
```

CardComponent:

```
const InfoCard = ({image_link, title}) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <h3>{title}</h3>
      <img src={image_link} alt={title} />
    </div>
  )
}

export default InfoCard;
```

Comment: You are amazing dude in 2022 and this is the best answer I found that suits my needs

Answer (score 0):

Hy, my solution:

**JSON object**

"url": "../assets/image/name.png"

Specify a path relative to the public folder

**Component**

<img className="classNames" src={'${url}'} alt="AltImage" />

***or***

src={url}

Works so and so. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Use backticks formatting in the require method then add your json variable name

```
<img src={require(`${element.avartarUrl}`)}
```

`element` being your json file name or the variable name you used then `avartarUrl` is the json variable you stored the image.